# Decomposition of $S^3$ as disjoint union of homeomorphic curves to the circle.

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

**Problem**
Let $S^3 = \{ (z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : |z_1| + |z_2| = 1 \}$. Show that's possible decompose the $S^3$ as disjoint union of simple and close curves.

**My Attempt**

Consider the system of differential equation in $\mathbb{C}^2$
$$
\dot{z_1} = \omega_1 z_1\\
\dot{z_2} = \omega_2 z_2
$$
where $\omega_k = \alpha_j + i \beta_j$, $j \in \{1,2 \}$, suposse that $Re(\omega_j) = 0$, and $Im(\omega_2)/Im(\omega_1) \in \mathbb{Q}$.
The solution of the system above, is $\varphi(t,z_1,z_2) = ( z_1 e^{\beta_1 i t}, z_2 e^{\beta_2 i t} )$. I now that $S^3$ is invariant by $ \varphi(t,z_1,z_2)$, because, if $(z_1,z_2) \in S^3$, then
$$
|z_1 e^{\beta_1 i t}| + |z_2 e^{\beta_2 i t}| = |z_1| |e^{\beta_1 i t}| + |z_2| |e^{\beta_1 i t}| = 1 
$$
by the existence and uniqueness theorem, given any initial condition, $z^1,z^2 \in S^3$ we have  $ \varphi(t,z^0) \cap \varphi(t,z^1) = \varnothing$. But, I now that in the torus, the condition of $Im(\omega_2)/Im(\omega_1) \in \mathbb{Q}$ imply that $\varphi(t)$ is a close curve. In the $S^3$ I not very sure, my intuition says "yes!" but I try think that in $S^2$, the two dimensional sphere, have $2$ critical points, but in the torus we don't have any critical point (talking about vector fields defined on these surfaces). In $S^3$ we have the same proprery that in $S^2$? (I refer about to these critical points)
How do I complete the proof?

Comment: Search for *Hopf fibration*.

Comment: In which context does the question occur? As Berci comments, the well-known *Hopf map*  $h : S^3 \to S^2$ has fibers which are homeomorphic to $S^1$. However, this map *usually* does not occur in the context of ode's. Nevertheless a relation seems to exist, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0112027.pdf

Comment: It's a exercice of ode list.
This exercice request for first: show that $T^2$ is invariant with respect to the flow of the system $\dot{z_1} = \omega_1 z_1, \dot{z_2} = \omega_2 z_2$ in $C^2$ 
Before, show that the solution of this system is periodic on $T^2$ iff $Re(\omega_1) = Re(\omega_2) =0$ and $Im(\omega_2)/Im(\omega_1)$ is rational, and if is irrational, show that the flow is dense in $T^2$.
Lastly, this question that I asked.